Unable to combine sources with Pipewire
I am trying to mix two audio source into one virtual audio source, that I later use with wf-recorder and slurp to capture a screen selection, my audio mic and my audio speakers output.
The virtual device is created with https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_combine_stream.html and works fine but does not mix the two sources properly. Here my config file:
$ cat ~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf.d/combined.conf
context.modules = [
    {
        name = libpipewire-module-combine-stream
        args = {
            combine.mode = source
            node.name = "combined"
            node.description = "Record Device"
            combine.props = {
                audio.position = [ FL FR ]
            }
            stream.rules = [
                {
                    matches = [
                        {
                            media.class = "Audio/Source"
                            node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__source"
                        }
                    ]
                    actions = {
                        create-stream = {
                        }
                    }
                }
                {
                    matches = [
                        {
                            media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                            node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink"
                        }
                    ]
                    actions = {
                        create-stream = {
                            stream.capture.sink = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]

If I remove the microphone from the config file, I can hear my speakers fine, but as soon as the two sources are in there, I hear only the mic.
Here is how run wf-recorder:
wf-recorder --audio="combined" -g "$(slurp)" -f

See my setup below:

OS: Fedora release 40 (Forty)
sway: 1.9
kernel: 6.10.3-200.fc40.x86_64
Wayland & Pipewire:

gnome-session-wayland-session.x86_64                   46.0-1.fc40       
libwayland-client.x86_64                               1.22.0-3.fc40     
libwayland-cursor.x86_64                               1.22.0-3.fc40     
libwayland-egl.x86_64                                  1.22.0-3.fc40     
libwayland-server.x86_64                               1.22.0-3.fc40     
pipewire.x86_64                                        1.0.7-2.fc40      
pipewire-alsa.x86_64                                   1.0.7-2.fc40      
pipewire-gstreamer.x86_64                              1.0.7-2.fc40      
pipewire-libs.x86_64                                   1.0.7-2.fc40      
pipewire-pulseaudio.x86_64                             1.0.7-2.fc40      
pipewire-utils.x86_64                                  1.0.7-2.fc40      
qemu-audio-pipewire.x86_64                             2:8.2.2-1.fc40    
qt5-qtwayland.x86_64                                   5.15.14-1.fc40    
qt6-qtwayland.x86_64                                   6.7.2-2.fc40      
vlc-plugin-pipewire.x86_64                             3-2.fc40          
xisxwayland.x86_64                                     2-4.fc40          
xorg-x11-server-Xwayland.x86_64                        24.1.2-1.fc40     
wf-recorder.x86_64                                     0.4.0-5.fc40

I have trouble debugging my setup as I'm not huge in audio, but could someone help me figure out what is wrong with my config file ?
